# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Mouse suddenly stopped working

Tags: 20.04, mouse, ssd, lts

Original Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation on a Western Digital 500 GB SSD worked without a problem for 6 months. On a day the mouse pointer would suddenly not respond. Looked for possible answers and tried everything that seemed remotely possible. No joy. Had the SSD tested at the local computer store. Was assured that it was in perfect working condition. Downloaded and re-installed the latest Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Worked as expected - for one day! Mouse pointer not moving. Today after a normal boot sequence the same problem cropped up again! Mouse not moving. Tried different mouse configurations - no difference. With a wired mouse, the LED underneath the mouse is illuminated - hence the USB port is ok. Tried another USB port - same result. Our second similar Ubuntu 20.04 installation is working as expected - same SSD, same setup, no problem after 6 months.
Subsequent development: Computer switched off overnight. This morning it booted up as normal and the mouse works! The case has a second extractor fan and the Gigabyte motherboard software shows that the hardware temperature is normal. What could be the cause of such erratic behavior?

Comment: Can you reboot, open the grub menu, and boot with an older kernel? It might be due to some regression in the new kernel (which might be fixed in a later version).

Comment: After a week of working normally, the mouse suddenly stopped working again. It seems that the problem was due to a malfunctioning Volcano wireless mouse. I removed the receiver unit from the USB port and rebooted the PC with a wired mouse. The mouse works as expected.  My conclusion is that the wireless mouse caused the USB port to stop functioning. Hard lesson learnt.